# inner element unaware of directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want the dropdown list to show when I mouse over the `<cart>` directive. the `mouseover` event is definitely firing and changing `scope.showDropdown` to true, as it should, but `<div class="cart">` seems unaware of this, even though I set `showDropdown`'s scope to `'='`. I'm kind of a beginner with custom directives. What am I missing here?

```
.directive('cart', ['Cart', function(Cart){
return {
    templateUrl: './templates/cart.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        showDropdown: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.showDropdown = false;
        scope.items = Cart.getItems;
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
            scope.showDropdown = true;
        });
        element.bind('mouseout', function(){
            scope.showDropdown = false;
        })
    }
}
}]);

app.controller('cartController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.showDropdown = false;
}])
```

and `cart.html`

```
<cart ng-controller="cartController">
Cart
    <div class="cart" ng-show="showDropdown">
        <ul>
            <li rg-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</cart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it as an argument to your directive:

```
 <div class="cart" show-dropdown="showDropdown" ng-show="showDropdown">
```

But I think the best solution would be to put the ng-show in your template. You can't hide all elements of the directive, otherwise how could you trigger the mouseover event?

Comment: Yeah, this is just a working model, I was actually using the word "cart" to mouseover, though for some reason I omitted it in the template, there will be a lot more. I directives shared the scope of heir parent controller by default, so that wrong? You can only get things into a directive through the attributes?

Comment: Either you define a scope (`scope: {...}`)and it becomes isolated (then you can only access the properties of your parent scope through $parent.propName) or through the attributes you defined on your directive, either you create a new (non-isolated) scope (`scope: true`) and you can access properties of your parent through prototypical inheritance, either you don't create a new scope.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I was not applying the changes I made to the scope. In the end I didn't need to be using either a controller or attributes.

```
.directive('cart', ['Cart', function(Cart){
return {
    templateUrl: './templates/cart.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: '=',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.items = Cart.getItems;
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
            scope.$apply('showDropdown = true');
        });
        element.bind('mouseout', function(){
            scope.$apply('showDropdown = false');
        })
    }
}
}]);

<cart>
Cart
    <div class="cart ng-hide" ng-show="showDropdown">
        <ul>
            <li rg-repeat="item in items" class="ng-binding"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</cart>
```

Comment: `scope: '='` doesn't make any sense IMHO. I believe you can just remove it.  + if you really only want to do this you can do it much easier with CSS. `.cart .cart-items { visibility: hidden; }
.cart:hover .cart-items { visibility: visible; }`